# Bulk-install Eclipse plugins with marketplace URL

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

I install Eclipse afresh quite often - on a new hire laptop, after re-imaging a personal machine or on a personal machine at home.

The most painful part is re-installing all my favorite plugins. I was looking for a way to automate the process, and found the Eclipse marketplace favorite section. The idea is to create a list of favorites which get a repo url which you can put into eclipse.

I've opened a public favorites list here: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/user/27670/favorites

But when I put that URL in eclipse, only the first item - PyDev - is shown:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? How can I set my Eclipse to read all items from my favorites list?**

Comment: Not a direct solution, but maybe a workaround: You can import a selection of plugins from a former installation directory via `File > Import > Install > From Existing Installation`. The current milestone build of Eclipse also provides some plugin conflict resolution mechanisms.

Comment: @jeppi Thanks, But I'm really looking for a URL I can send new employees that would work with future versions of Eclipse.

Comment: I've opened a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409646

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking, un-checking and re-checking "Group items by category" did the trick. I've updated the [bug report at the Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409646).

[image]